# Forward slash problem in image path in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

In my Laravel website image name is

`images/campaign/4965d649233e1436ece21804ff4eb62b.jpeg`

Actual image path is `http://localhost/fund/storage/app/images/campaign/4965d649233e1436ece21804ff4eb62b.jpeg`

But in my blade template when I use this path it automatically converted into 
`http://localhost/fund/storage/app/images%2Fcampaign%2F4965d649233e1436ece21804ff4eb62b.jpeg`

That's why my image is not shown.

**Img src code in blade template**

```
src="{{url('/storage/app',$response->large_image)}}"
```

Why `/` is automatically replaced by `%2F`  and how to solve it?

Anyone help please?

Comment: Do you echo the path of the image like `{!! $image_name !!}` or like `{{ $image_name }}`?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan.. like second one   `{{ $image_name }}`

Comment: Hmm, can you append your code to your question? Like the part of the script where the path is echoed?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan..update my post..please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the blade to the following:

```
src="{{url('/storage/app/'.$response->large_image)}}"
```

I've changed the comma to a dot, which appends the path of the image to the `/storage/app` part, so it doesn't encode that last part.

Comment: Might need to be `'/storage/app/'.`, but depends if `$response->large_image` starts with a `/` or not.

Comment: yess !! It's done... just little correction please. use `/storage/app/` instead of `/storage/app`

Answer (score 0):

no need to use a concatenation when you use double quotes instead of single quotes

```
src='{{url("/storage/app/$response->large_image")}}'
```